# Multiple codeigniter application on same server using same session userdata variable name

Tags: codeigniter, session-variables

I have multiple CI application on same server using same session userdata variable name.

In some controller on first CI app

```
$sess_data['username'] = $username;
$this->session->set_userdata('logged_app',$sess_data);
```

In some controller on another CI app but in same host server.

```
if (!isset($this->session->userdata['logged_app'])) { echo "success";}
```

Isn't this a security hole? What happen if the applications are in different host?

Comment: as soon as they are on different hosts - you have a different server and therefore different session data - so this won't work anymore, according to your question, you've to be a bit more specific - are your applications using different domains or how are they even connected together ?

Comment: thank you @sintakonte for your quick response. I'm developing a single sign-on mechanism on multiple CI application in different subdomain, but in same host environment (e.g same webserver). I'm little bit worried about this issued that someone could create identical session variable name on remote host therefore can access my controller.

Answer (score 0):

If they all use different domains even on the same host that shouldn't be a problem. If they share the same domain, then that's a problem because users will be logged in all your app on that server.